# full-width background image limited height

Tags: html, css

I want to get a full-screen background image but only the width, not the height, like [here](https://www.edx.org/)

I've been playing around with `background-size:cover;` but that covers the whole page - and I just want a certain height to be covered.

Answer (score 2):

The site you mention is just using a standard background-image on a div that has a fixed `height` and `width: 100%`.

For example the site you mention uses:

```
header {
   height: 460px;
   margin-top: -69px;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 0px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Notice the height in the code block, `background-image: cover` just means scale the background image to fit the space.

Comment: thanks, but when I try that the image 1. does not cover the width of the screen and 2. leaves a white bar on the left side...

Answer (score 2):

so I found what I was looking for:

***CSS:***

```
#header-wrapper{
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: auto;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="100%" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
</div>
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: better yet, just this works as well: <img src="image.jpg" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;">

Answer (score 2):

How about `background-size: 100% 80%` (for example).
You can change the second value, which is the height.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zq83e/1/).